# Kicad Version 5.1.0 Missing shortcuts

Tags: kicad

I have some questions regarding PCBnew of kicad 5.1.0.

1. I cannot find how to global spread all the footprints after reading the netlist. There is no "mode button or footprint mode" any longer.
2. How can I change the size of several footprints' pads at the same time, avoiding the need to open each footprint one by one with the footprint editor and change its footprints?
3. I cannot find the button "update footprint into current board" any more in the footprint editor, so that my changes can be applied to my PCB.

In general, is there a way to manage the PCBnew toolbars?

Edit:

This is the top toolbar of this version's footprint editor. The "update footprint" button is missing:

[image: FootprintEditor]

This is the top toolbar of this versions PCBnew. The modes buttons are missing:

[image: PCBnew]

Answer (score 3):

This is a few questions, so I'll list the answers in the numerical order you have asked the question.

1. After reading the netlist, your footprints should be spread automatically.  Therefore this menu item was removed.  Note that the preferred method for updating pcbnew from eeschema is now "Tool->Update PCB From Schematic (F8)".  This avoids the netlist step.
2. There is no program-based way to edit groups of pads from the board editor.  You can edit the footprint and then replace all of the footprints on the board with your edited version.
3. When you open a footprint from the board and change it, those will be saved to the footprint on the board

[image: Save Changes to Board]

There is no general way to change the toolbar.  Add your vote to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/kicad/+bug/1811564) if this feature would be important to you (just check the "This affects me too" button at the top).